# Auto three level zoom in leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet

What I am looking for is say there is 1 to 8 level zoom in simple leaflet example.

http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html

Say I have variable called distance. If value of distance is 4000 it should start zoom from 1 to 3 zoom level automatically. Once it reaches zoom 3 it should again go back to zoom 1 and keep doing this automatic. Once the value of distance value is changed to 3000 it should start from zoom 2 to 4. Again once the value of distance value is changed to 2000 it should start from zoom 3 to 5.

Can anyone share the code for the above same.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: It should do auto zoom level every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I made this function

```
function autoZoom(map,startLevel,endLevel, time){
                var i=startLevel;
                var reverse=false;
                window.setInterval(function () {
                    map.setZoom(i);
                    if(i==startLevel && reverse ) reverse=false;
                    if(i<endLevel && !reverse ){
                        i++;
                    }
                    else{
                        reverse=true;
                        i--;
                    }
                }, time);


            }
```

use for example,

```
if(distance==4000){
    autoZoom(map,1,3,5000)
}
if(distance==3000){
    autoZoom(map,2,4,5000)
}
```

Yo can test it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/osk386/570Lubb2/

greetings..